# How many gems does it cost to go from Town Hall 9 to 12?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am at Town Hall level 9, how many Gems will I need to purchase to completely upgrade to Town Hall 12?

Comment: are you also counting gems for instant building? or just gems to get resources to upgrade?

Answer (score 5):

### Town Hall 9

1. Elixir: 140,847,100 **<= not including walls**
2. Gold: 220,081,850 **<= not including walls**
3. Walls: 375,000,000 **<= can be a mixture of gold and elixir**
4. Dark Elixir: 4,417,500
5. Gems: 505,664
6. US Dollars: 3611 **<= Roughly**

---

### Town Hall 10

1. Elixir: 215,950,000 **<= not including walls**
2. Gold: 482,148,000 **<= not including walls**
3. Walls: 587,500,000 **<= can be a mixture of gold and elixir**
4. Dark Elixir: 4,100,000
5. Gems: 680,422
6. US Dollars: 4859 **<= Roughly**

---

### Town Hall 11

1. Elixir: 346,600,000 **<= not including walls**
2. Gold: 731,805,500 **<= not including walls**
3. Walls: 1,287,500,000 **<= can be a mixture of gold and elixir**
4. Dark Elixir: 5,275,000
5. Gems: 1,077,271
6. US Dollars: 7694 **<= Roughly**

---

### Town Hall 12

1. Elixir: 333,700,000 **<= not including walls**
2. Gold: 603,030,500 **<= not including walls**
3. Walls: 500,000,000 **<= can be a mixture of gold and elixir**
4. Dark Elixir: 5,810,000
5. Gems: 761,233
6. US Dollars: 5437 **<= Roughly**

---

### Total

1. Elixir: 1,037,097,100 **<= not including walls**
2. Gold: 2,037,065,850 **<= not including walls**
3. Walls: 2,750,000,000 **<= can be a mixture of gold and elixir**
4. Dark Elixir: 19,602,500
5. Gems: 3,024,590
6. US Dollars: 21,602 **<= Roughly**

---

Numbers subject to change with new updates and gem discounts. Additionally these numbers to do not include the cost of instant building.

Comment: $20k? Makes me wish I was the one that created Clash of Clans...